# TypeScript: the type constraint prompt is incorrect when using "keyof TYPE" for index access

Tags: typescript

this is my type declaration

```
interface Events {
    error: Array<ErrorEvent>,
    enqueue: Array<EnqueueEvent>,
    dequeue: Array<DequeueEvent>,
}
```

an example

```
protected listen<T extends keyof Events>(eventName: T, handler: Events[T] extends Array<infer E> ? E : never): void {
   this.events[eventName].push(*handler*);
   // .push type prompt: Array<T>.push( items: (ErrorEvent & EnqueueEvent & DequeueEvent)[]):number
}
```

why??? Shouldn't it be one of the values of Events? Why does it become a cross-type and an array?

There are no issues with the function call and parameter passing. The issue lies specifically in this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does it become a cross-type and an array?

It becomes a cross-type because TypeScript isn't quite smart enough to disentangle the logic that binds `eventName` and `handler` together in this context. It doesn't really become an array - `array.push()` takes a variable number of arguments and that is expressed as a spread parameter.

To readjust things so that TypeScript is able to follow along, try changing `Events` to a mapped type onto an interface where the values are the handler type, not the array-of-handler type:

```
interface EventHandlers {
  error: ErrorEvent;
  enqueue: EnqueueEvent;
  dequeue: DequeueEvent;
}

type Events = {
  [K in keyof EventHandlers]: Array<EventHandlers[K]>;
}
```

Now you can directly access the event handler type through this, instead of indirectly via the `infer` method:

```
protected listen<T extends keyof Events>(eventName: T, handler: EventHandlers[T]): void {
   this.events[eventName].push(handler);
}
```

Comment: fine... thank you. it seems that's the only way to go